# Calculate Difference in Dates Google Spreadsheet

Tags: date, spreadsheet

Ok so I'm not talking about calculating the difference between 2 dates in different cells.  I know this may not be possible but I thought I'd ask anyway since I can't seem to find anything on it.

What I'm trying to do is setup a column that auto-calculates the difference between a date value entered into it and the current date.  The purpose is to create an auto-filling point system.  Where an entry receives points equivalent to the difference in due date and current date.  So if someone submits a job request today, 5/30/14, and wants it back by 6/5/14 then they would receive 6 points, which is the number of days difference between now and then.  However, I want this all done in a single cell, not calculating between 2 cells.  I want each cell within the column to auto-calculate itself when I enter a due date, and transform the entered date value to the number of days difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just subtract to get the answer in days

```
A1 =DateValue("12/25/2000")
A2 =Today()
A3 =A2-A1

A3 is in days. (4904)
```